# Django Query Optimization - Using Itertools

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have an educational site that serves up curriculum based upon Grade level.

1. The GradeLevel table stores all of the possible Grade Levels. Then I have LessonCategories and LessonCurriculum tables.
2. The GradeLevel table has reverse relationships established with the curriculum and categories tables.
3. I loop through each grade in the GradeLevel table, (8 grades), and grab the respective, curriculum and categories along the way.
4. Upon completion, I stuff all of the collected curriculum and categories into a list and and pass that to my template.

Now, the problem is that Django is evaluating each query AT LEAST twice. Once for the initial request and the second when I put it into the list. (I am using itertools to chain the results. Itertools is causing the queries to be run again.) This is having the adverse effect of slowing my server down to a crawl.

My question is if someone could take a look at my models and queries and make a suggestion as to a better way to query as to avoid and/or mitigate this MAJOR performance bottle-neck.

**GradeLevel Model:**

```
class GradeLevel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Grade',max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    fullname = models.CharField('Description',max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

**LessonCategory Model:**

```
class LessonCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    ...
    gradelevel = models.ManyToManyField(GradeLevel, related_name='grade_cats', null=True, blank=True)
```

**LessonCurriculum:**

```
class LessonCurriculum(models.Model):         
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    ...
    gradelevel = models.ManyToManyField(GradeLevel, related_name='grade_curriculum', null=True, blank=True)
```

My View:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter

def my_view(request):
    grade_pk =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='pre-k')
    grade_pk_categories = grade_pk.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_pk_galleries = grade_pk.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_k =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='k')
    grade_k_categories = grade_k.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_k_galleries = grade_k.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_1 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='1')
    grade_1_categories = grade_1.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_1_galleries = grade_1.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_2 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='2')
    grade_2_categories = grade_2.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_2_galleries = grade_2.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_3 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='3')
    grade_3_categories = grade_3.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_3_galleries = grade_3.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_4 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='4')
    grade_4_categories = grade_4.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_4_galleries = grade_4.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_5 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='5')
    grade_5_categories = grade_5.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_5_galleries = grade_5.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_6 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='6')
    grade_6_categories = grade_6.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_6_galleries = grade_6.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_7 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='7')
    grade_7_categories = grade_7.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_7_galleries = grade_7.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    grade_8 =  GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title='8')
    grade_8_categories = grade_8.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_8_galleries = grade_8.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)

    gallery_list = list(set(sorted(chain(grade_pk_categories,grade_pk_galleries,grade_k_categories,grade_k_galleries,grade_1_categories,grade_1_galleries,grade_2_categories,grade_2_galleries,grade_3_categories,grade_3_galleries,grade_4_categories,grade_4_galleries,grade_5_categories,grade_5_galleries,grade_6_categories,grade_6_galleries,grade_7_categories,grade_7_galleries,grade_8_categories,grade_8_galleries), key=attrgetter('display_order'))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is [chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). This will prevent the queries from being run more than once.

```
gallery_list = tuple(chain.from_iterable(grade_pk_categories,grade_pk_galleries,grade_k_categories,grade_k_galleries,grade_1_categories,grade_1_galleries,grade_2_categories,grade_2_galleries,grade_3_categories,grade_3_galleries,grade_4_categories,grade_4_galleries,grade_5_categories,grade_5_galleries,grade_6_categories,grade_6_galleries,grade_7_categories,grade_7_galleries,grade_8_categories,grade_8_galleries))
```

You also want to be sorting after you run your items through a `set`, not before.

```
gallery_list = list(sorted(frozenset(gallery_list), key=attrgetter('display_order')))
```

I would reconsider how you are going about fetching all of this data. You are doing two query for each grade level when you could probably replace it with one or two queries for all of the data.

At the very least you could use a `for loop` to reduce the amount of code you have:

```
grade_titles = ['pre-k', 'k', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
gallery_list = []
for grade_title in grade_titles:
    grade = GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().get(title=grade_title)
    grade_categories = grade_pk.grade_cats.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    grade_galleries = grade_pk.grade_curriculum.filter(active=True,featured=True)
    gallery_list.extend(grade_categories)
    gallery_list.extend(grade_galleries)
gallery_list = list(sorted(frozenset(gallery_list), key=attrgetter('display_order')))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let me give this a shot.

Comment: BTW, you can also add `.all()` to the end of a query to fetch it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I would go a bit ahead and optimize @NathanVillaescusa's answer a bit more

```py
grade_titles = ['pre-k', 'k', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

# Turn list into list of Q items
queries = [models.Q(title=grade_title) for grade_title in grade_titles]

# Take one item of the list
query = queries.pop()

# OR the Q objects with the ones remaining in the list
for item in queries:
    query |= item

grades = GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().filter(query)
# grades should have everything you need and operation is more CPU
# and less DB bound now
```

Comment: While this is a neat way to do things, if grades pre-k through 8 are the only grades at the school, then none of this is even needed. Just do `grades = GradeLevel.objects.prefetch_related().all()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate @NathanVillaescusa? Grades pre-k thru 8 are the only grades at the school.

Comment: True. Since almost the whole data is fetched, it might as well be cached or stored in-memory through some other means.

Comment: The query here is explicitly including each grade level which is the same thing as including everything. The query ends up looking like `WHERE title = 'pre-k' OR title = 'k' OR title = '1' ... OR title = '8'` which is unnecessary.

Comment: Right. I understand. I mis-understood your comment. Thank you for clarifying.